# Access images folder tomcat 9

Tags: rest, tomcat, jersey, jersey-2.0

i have a problem using jersey. Through jersey i want to save users, each user has an image, i don't want to save the image in the database as a blob type. I want to save the filename of the image in the database and access it from the client side through jersey. For example lets say i have a filename 123.png, after i save the image through jersey i want to access it like this

**localhost:8080/images/users/123.png**

What i found is that i can't achieve this through jersey, but i can access files inside webapp tomcat's folder, the problem i found with this approach is that whenever i uploaded a new image i had to redeploy tomcat. Do you know if there is a solution to my problem? I want to access this folder without redeploying when a new file appears in the folder.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what i was doing wrong. I was addding images inside project and not inside webapps folder inside tomcat! So if you add any file inside webapps folder in Tomcat you can access it without redeploy tomcat.